# Cannot use deep learning datasets maker in QGIS

Tags: qgis, deep-learning

We are using QGIS deep learning datasets maker. I am trying to create training data with satellite image data and data from a `.shp` file.
When I run the program, I get the following error.

```
An error has occurred while executing Python code: 

RuntimeError: type=xyz&url=http://www.google.cn/maps/vt?lyrs%3Ds@189%26gl%3Dcn%26x%3D%7Bx%7D%26y%3D%7By%7D%26z%3D%7Bz%7D&zmax=18&zmin=0: No such file or directory 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bokutotu/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/deep-learning-datasets-maker/split_rs_data.py", line 315, in run
    rasterize(ras_path, vec_path, output)
  File "/home/bokutotu/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/deep-learning-datasets-maker/utils/rasterize.py", line 8, in rasterize
    ras_ds = gdal.Open(ras_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 4112, in Open
    return _gdal.Open(*args)
RuntimeError: type=xyz&url=http://www.google.cn/maps/vt?lyrs%3Ds@189%26gl%3Dcn%26x%3D%7Bx%7D%26y%3D%7By%7D%26z%3D%7Bz%7D&zmax=18&zmin=0: No such file or directory


Python version: 3.10.4 (main, Apr  2 2022, 09:04:19) [GCC 11.2.0] 
QGIS version: 3.22.4-Białowieża Białowieża, exported 

Python Path:
/usr/share/qgis/python
/home/bokutotu/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/home/bokutotu/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins
/usr/lib/python310.zip
/usr/lib/python3.10
/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload
/home/bokutotu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/home/bokutotu/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
```

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using bro?

Comment: @nr_aus `QGIS version: 3.22.4-Białowieża Białowieża, exported`

Comment: This is strange: `Python version: 3.10.4` Currently QGIS does not support this version of Python. QGIS version `3.24.1-Tisler` only supports Python version `3.9.5`.

Comment: this may be because `deep learning datasets maker` uses not qgis python but system python.